# I can not show the gragh on pop up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have been fighting with the following problem for two days and still I have trouble:

I am using Raphael graph plug in to plot my points and show it to the user which is fine and works properly also I am using boxer plugin for making a pop up window and it works a well

for example for chart I use the following code which works:

```
var r1 = Raphael("trend_chart1", w, h);
 r1.gridDrawn = false;
var h1 = $("#trend_chart1").height();
var w1 = $("#trend_chart1").width();
var le1=["Sureness"] ;
var colo1=["#CC0000"];
drawTrend(r1, w1, h1,0.7, sureness, date, le1, 0, colo1);
```

and `trend_chart1` is a div that I made it dynamically  also I use boxer like this:

```
$.boxer($('<div  class="inline_content"><div id="d" style="width:100%;float:left;height:100%;"></div></div>'));
```

which works fine and now another div with id of `d` is created.
till now everything is good but as soon as I try to show chart in boxer as follow javascript debugger says that it can not recognize div with id of `d`:

```
$("#trend_chart1").click(function () {

    alert("salam");
    $.boxer($('<div  class="inline_content"><div id="d" style="width:100%;float:left;height:100%;"></div></div>'));
    var hh = $("#d").height();
    var ww = $("#d").width();
    var rtest = Raphael("d", w, h);
    rtest.gridDrawn = false;
    drawTrend(rtest, ww, hh, 0.7, happiness, date, le4, 0, colo4);
});
```

but `d` is added by boxer dynamically and I can see it in the html code at run time when I use inspect element of chrome.

I appreciate if anyone can help?

**Update: for pop up I use the following:**

[**pop up plug in**](http://formstone.it/components/Boxer/demo/index.html)

**Update:**

from my observation it seems that div with id of d is created but can not be recognized by Raphael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you're accessing the element before it is loaded in the document. Use callback provided by the plugin.

```
    $("#trend_chart1").click(function () {        
        alert("salam");
        $.boxer($('<div  class="inline_content"><div id="d" style="width:100%;float:left;height:100%;"></div></div>'), {
            callback: function() {
                var hh = $("#d").height();
                var ww = $("#d").width();
                var rtest = Raphael("d", w, h);
                rtest.gridDrawn = false;
                drawTrend(rtest, ww, hh, 0.7, happiness, date, le4, 0, colo4);
            }
        });            
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a million yes I do not get any error anymore but even instead of that gragh when I add $("#d").text("dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd");                         I can not see it and when I check it in inspect element it is there. So it means the text is added but it is not shown do you have any idea?

Comment: Try removing float:left; Possibility is that the element is appearing where it is not intended to. Also check the "display" style of the element. A "display:none;" might be inherited from any parent CSS.